# setup celerybeat with supervisord

Tags: python, celery, supervisord, celerybeat

I am confused on how to use celery beat with the supervisord process control system.  The following code is an example of a celerybeat program on supervisord.

```
; ================================
;  celery beat supervisor example
; ================================

[program:celerybeat]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=celery beat -A myapp --schedule /var/lib/celery/beat.db --loglevel=INFO

; remove the -A myapp argument if you are not using an app instance

directory=/path/to/project
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=999
```

On the 7th line it has the following code: `/var/lib/celery/beat.db`, what is this, and what would I replace this path with?  Similarily, what would I replace this path with `/var/log/celery/beat.log`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command help: --schedule is:

```
  -s SCHEDULE, --schedule=SCHEDULE
                    Path to the schedule database. The extension '.db'
                    will be appended to the filename. Default: celerybeat-
                    schedule
```

And from the [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html):

Custom scheduler classes can be specified on the command-line (the -S argument). The default scheduler is celery.beat.PersistentScheduler, which is simply keeping track of the last run times in a local database file (a shelve).

django-celery also ships with a scheduler that stores the schedule in the Django database:

`$ celery -A proj beat -S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler`

Using django-celery‘s scheduler you can add, modify and remove periodic tasks from the Django Admin.

Comment: Hi, I am using django-celery so 'djcelery' for my django project.  I am getting this error: can't find command 'celery'.  How would I set path to the celery command in supervisor?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the version u r using is old (like mine) the command would be celerybeat instead of celery. For example, I use `./manage.py celerybeat -S $CELERY_SCHEDULER --logfile=$CELERY_LOG_DIR/celerybeat.log`